# Understanding creation of acts_as_anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, dsl

I successfully created a gem having some classes and modules to be'ing able to to something like that in ANY kind of class in a Rails project:

```
class AnyRubyOrActiveModelClass
  acts_as_anything [:foo, :bar]

  def foo
    .. do some foo
  end

  def self.bar
    .. do some bar
  end
end
```

To do so I created a Module in my gem that looked something like that:

```
module InstanceMagic
  class << self.class.superclass
  define_method(:acts_as_anything) do |methods|
    self.class_eval do
      include ClassMagic
      .. do some alias_method with given methods
    end
  end
end
```

This module successfully aliased my method :foo from the example above, the second module ClassMagic did the same for my :bar class method (following the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799760/understanding-method-added-for-class-methods)).

In a testproject that approach worked very well. In a real life project it led to interference with another gem taking a - maybe similar - approach. This gem complained about missing methods in a class even when I only integrated my gem into the project - not even integrated acts_as_anything into the class.

So I broke down my code to only that:

```
module InstanceMagic
  class << self.class.superclass
  define_method(:acts_as_anything) do |methods|
    #really empty here
  end
end
```

As a result the other gem still breaks.

I used class << self.class.superclass to explicitly extend Object, so that even non ActiveSomething classes but ALL classes are affected and my acts_as_anything is available. So I remain with three questions.

Why do the last 5 lines of code break another gem and making it complain about missing methods it's trying to dynamically create? I would like to understand.

Is there a better approach to achieve my goal?

When I use method_added and singleton_method_added (what I actually do inside my modules), should I look for these methods whether they already exist, alias the "original" ones, insert my ones and call the original ones after I have done my job?

Knowing this is a lot I still hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Thank you. 
Felix

Comment: Could you add any of the errors or at least the gems that conflict? Why use self.class.superclass ? self.class.superclass in the context of a module will always be Object, why not just say that for readability? I'd like to help if I could get some more context about the errors.

Comment: Shawn, thanks for your suggestions. Their'e welcome. The gem that complains to work is: friendly_id. If I startup my app at the console, I get the following errors:

/Users/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299@ft3/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:1998:in `method_missing_without_paginate':NoMethodError: undefined method `has_friendly_id' for #<Class:0x1059fc148>
ruby-1.8.7-p299 > User
  User Columns (2.9ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
NoMethodError:   SQL (1.9ms)   SHOW TABLES
undefined method `has_friendly_id' for #<Class:0x105d74438>

Comment: It seems the gem is unable to register its own methods. If I remove my gem from the Gemfile, friendly_id comes back to normal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is some sort of order dependency (long shot). Try to put your code in an initializer in the rails app and see if it still causes the same problems.

Comment: Confusing: If I put the last mentioned lines of code into an initializer, there is no problem for the other Gem to load and function. If I put these lines inside a file in my gem's lib dir, the error mentioned above occures.

Comment: I'm not sure about the details, but it's probably an order issue. Hope this has helped.