# Getting the name of the defined method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I know that I can capture the moment of a method definition by using `set_trace_func`.

```
set_trace_func ->event, file, line, method, binding, klass{
  if event == "c-call" and method == :method_added
    # The moment of method definition
  end
}
```

1. Is it possible to capture the name of the method being defined at such moment? I know that the class can be captured by `eval("self", binding)`. What code can I put inside the block shown above to capture the method name?
2. Is it further possible to get the format of the arguments for the method being defined (the required arguments, the rest of the arguments, and their names as is in the source)?

Answer (score 1):

Outside of `set_trace_func`, you could use `Module.method_added`:

```
class Test
  def self.method_added(method_name)
    puts "#{method_name} added to #{self}"
  end

  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end

$ ruby test.rb
# => foo added to Test
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799760/understanding-method-added-for-class-methods

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation.

The `Kernel.set_trace_func` proc allows you catch an `id` parameter. This—most times—is the function name.

However, learning from your example, you can also get the current running method using `eval("__method__", binding)` …but I think this only gets the methods you have defined in your classes.